Trying to time the "in" operator
I have a question about how the in operator works internally. So to test it I tried to graph the time it takes to find a member of a list, in different parts of the list.
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# list size
size = 100000
# number of points
n = 100000

# display for not having to count zeros
if size >= 1000000:
    new_size = str(int(size/1000000))+"M"
else:
    new_size = str(int(size/1000))+"K"

if n >= 1000000:
    new_n = str(int(n/10000000))+"M"
elif n >= 1000:
    new_n = str(int(n/1000))+"K"
else:
    new_n = n

lst = list(range(size))
result = []
for number in range(0,size+1,int(size/n)):
    start_time = time.time_ns()
    if number in lst:
        end_time = time.time_ns()
        total_time = (end_time-start_time)/1000000000 #convert ns to seconds
        result.append([total_time,number])
        print(number,total_time)

x_values, y_values = zip(*result)
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c='red', marker='o',s=5)
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.title(f'List length: {new_size}\nNumber of points: {new_n}\n\nTime to find number in list')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

From what I saw, in works internally by calling iter which sequentially takes all elements of the iterable, starting from the first. So I would expect that searching further in a list takes more and more time.
The list has to be above a certain length so that python takes a long enough time to find the number that we can measure, but fiddling around with different list sizes and number of points I found out that the points cluster around vertical lines on multiples of 0.001s, which is very bizzare to me. I could see some horizontal lines forming due to how python works internally, but not vertical ones. I even used time.time_ns() to have even more time precision, but it still happens.
I mean, how can it take the same time to find 539 and 94,598 inside a [0,1, ... 100000] list if it always starts from 0?


Never time just once. Usually we time 1000 or much more iteration (check e.g. the timeit). Clock precision is not great, and you may be at beginning or at end of a tick, and machine may had to do other things, Also are you sure you can measure at _ns precision?

Definitely best to use timeit, it will utilize whatever the best time source is for your platform and will run lots of trials for a more consistent result.

What does it look like if you just use time.perf_counter_ns() instead of time.time_ns()?

@GiacomoCatenazzi They already do time 100000 times, not just once.

@nocomment: start_time and end_time are split only by a if (so timing of each time.time_ns() may be more relevant than what we test). -- A timing of a loop is better then a loop of timing.

@Barmar What makes you think that shouldn't be done? Does SO have a guideline that says so?

@nocomment See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts. The arguments there are that it's appropriate to remove greetings and thanks, but not to edit if that's the only thing wrong.

@Barmar That's not what the (top-voted) answers there are saying. They're rather saying the opposite. (I myself btw would've welcomed already just the removal of the leading "So", which I always find highly irritating.)

@nocomment The top-voted answers are addressing the question of whether we want those lines in questions, NOT whether you should edit a question ONLY to remove them. Unfortunately, all other questions related to this just get closed as a duplicate of that one.

@nocomment See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333065/a-moderator-messaged-me-that-my-edits-which-only-remove-thanks-and-alike-are-d

@Barmar To me it looks like you're misreading/misrepresenting things.

This test seems to suggest to me that searching for a number in a list takes longer and longer based on where the item falls in the list.
import timeit

setup = """
size = 1_000_000
size_minus_one = size - 1
data = list(range(size))
"""

print(timeit.timeit("0 in data", setup=setup, number=1_000))
print(timeit.timeit("size_minus_one in data", setup=setup, number=1_000))

I assume some people are not satisfied with that answer as the vertical bars are not "explained". Let's do that as well.
The vertical bars are an artifact of the resolution of the time.time_ns(). Using time.perf_counter_ns() as recommended by @no-comment gives us the following result confirming that the time to find an item in a list is directly proportional to the location of the item in the list.

Via this code:
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# list size
size = 100000
# number of points
n = 100000

# display for not having to count zeros
if size >= 1000000:
    new_size = str(int(size/1000000))+"M"
else:
    new_size = str(int(size/1000))+"K"

if n >= 1000000:
    new_n = str(int(n/10000000))+"M"
elif n >= 1000:
    new_n = str(int(n/1000))+"K"
else:
    new_n = n

clock = time.perf_counter_ns
lst = list(range(size))
result = []
for number in range(0,size+1, int(size/n)):
    start_time = clock()
    if number in lst:
        result.append([clock() - start_time, number])

x_values, y_values = zip(*result)
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c='red', marker='o',s=5)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.title(f'List length: {new_size}\nNumber of points: {new_n}\n\nTime to find number in list')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


Indeed both time.perf_counter_ns() and timeit make it work as intended and show that the time is proportional to how far in the list you are searching (albeit sometimes with some huge deviations).
@JonSG This was my first post so I didn't know how things worked, thanks for the heads up!
